# タグ名の変動するサイトからスクレイピングを行いたいです。

Tags: javascript, 正規表現, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-spreadsheet

会社名をスクレイピングしたいのですが、同じサイトでも会社によってタグの数字が変化します。

以下のページで紹介されているParserは、Webスクレイピング用のライブラリです。

[【GAS】Parserライブラリの使い方｜インストール手順と使用方法](https://tetsuooo.net/gas/1944/)

例:

```html
<a href="/2024/company/r308300069/">
<a href="/2024/company/r505050505/">
```

この場合、以下のコードでは会社名だけをスクレイピングすることができません。
正規表現か何かで、変動する数字の場所だけを抽象化して記述する方法はないでしょうか？

```js
function ScrapCOMP() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetURL  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('URL貼り付け'), true);
  var sheetWork  = spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('ペースト&作業用シート'), true);
  
for(i=2; i<=11; i++){
  var V   =  i   +    10;
  var r   =  i   -    1;
  let URL = sheetURL.getRange('A'  +   i).getValue();
  let response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(URL);
  let content = response.getContentText("utf-8");
  var COMPNAME = Parser.data(content).from('<a href="/2024/company/r308300069/">').to('</a>').iterate();
  console.log(COMPNAME);
  console.log(typeof(COMPNAME));
}
}
```

ログの例

```
----------
11:57:03    情報  [ 'head>\n<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge">\n<meta charset="UTF-8">\n<link rel="canonical" href="https://job.rikunabi.com/2024/company/r383010072/">\n<link rel="stylesheet" href="/2024/static/add/css/hon/company/top/ts-h-index.css">\n\n\n\t<script src="/2024/static/add/js/ima-polyfill.js"></script>\n\t<script src="/2024/static/add/js/browser-polyfill.min.js"></script>\n\t<!--[if lt IE 9]>\n\t\t<script src="/2024/static/add/js/console-polyfill.js"></script>\n\t\t<script src="/2024/static/add/js/classList.min.js"></script>\n\t\t<![endif]-->\n\t<script src="/2024/static/add/js/jquery.1.12.x.min.js"></script>\n\n<!-- BEGIN /intra/navg/meta/companyTop.jsp -->\r\n<title>株式会社真伯連合の新卒採用・企業情報2024</title>\r\n<meta name="description" content="株式会社真伯連合の2024年度新卒採用・企業情報。文系・理系不問。人物重視の採用。">\r\n<meta name="keywords" content="就活,就職活動,新卒採用">\r\n\r\n<!-- END /intra/navg/meta/companyTop.jsp -->\n\n<script>\nwindow.env = {\n     context:\'/2024\',\n     csrf: \'\'\n}\n</script>\n\n<!-- Start Visual Website Optimizer Asynchronous Code -->\n<script type=\'text/javascript\'>\nvar _vwo_code=(function(){\nvar account_id=290960,\nsettings_tolerance=2000,\nlibrary_tolerance=2500,\nuse_existing_jquery=false,\n/* DO NOT EDIT BELOW THIS LINE */\nf=false,d=document;return{use_existing_jquery:function(){return use_existing_jquery;},library_tolerance:function(){return library_tolerance;},finish:function(){if(!f){f=true;var a=d.getElementById(\'_vis_opt_path_hides\');if(a)a.parentNode.removeChild(a);}},finished:function(){return f;},load:function(a){var b=d.createElement(\'script\');b.src=a;b.type=\'text/javascript\';b.innerText;b.onerror=function(){_vwo_code.finish();};d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0].appendChild(b);},init:function(){settings_timer=setTimeout(\'_vwo_code.finish()\',settings_tolerance);var a=d.createElement(\'style\'),b=\'body{opacity:0 !important;filter:alpha(opacity=0) !important;background:none !important;}\',h=d.getElementsByTagName(\'head\')[0];a.setAttribute(\'id\',\'_vis_opt_path_hides\');a.setAttribute(\'type\',\'text/css\');if(a.styleSheet)a.styleSheet.cssText=b;else a.appendChild(d.createTextNode(b));h.appendChild(a);this.load(\'//dev.visualwebsiteoptimizer.com/j.php?a=\'+account_id+\'&u=\'+encodeURIComponent(d.URL)+\'&r=\'+Math.random());return settings_timer;}};}());_vwo_settings_timer=_vwo_code.init();\n</script>\n<!-- End Visual Website Optimizer Asynchronous Code -->\n\n</head>\n\n<body>\n<div class="ts-h-l-root">\n<div class="ts-h-l-header">\n<div class="ts-h-l-header-container">\n<div class="ts-h-l-header-container-inner ts-s-cf">\n<div class="ts-h-l-header-logo">\n<a href="/2024/" target="_blank"><img src="/2024/static/common/contents/logos/rikunabiStu/image/popup_headerlogo.gif" alt="リクナビ2024" border="0">' ]
11:57:03    情報  object
```

Comment: `Parser` というのは何ですか？
外部のライブラリでしたら、ドキュメントなどへのリンクを追記して下さい。

Comment: Webスクレイピングを行うための外部ライブラリです
説明不足でした

Comment: ライブラリの追記を拝見しました。
このような紹介記事は信頼性、完全性、正確性が不十分です。
[作者のブログ](https://www.kutil.org/2016/01/easy-data-scrapping-with-google-apps.html)と[コード](https://script.google.com/home/projects/1Mc8BthYthXx6CoIz90-JiSzSafVnT6U3t0z_W3hLTAX5ek4w0G_EIrNw/edit)が見つかりました。
ライセンスが不明ですし、これくらいの機能ならば正規表現などを直接使ってもよさそうなので、私ならこのライブラリは使いません。
HTMLを正確に解析する必要が生じたら、[XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service?hl=ja)や[cheerio for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs)を検討します。
（なお、色々な制限が有ることとは思いますが、Node.js などを使う方が結局は簡単で早く終ると思います）

Comment: おっしゃることは分かりますが、私自身は勉強中の為自力でスクレイピングを行うコードが書けず、外部ライブラリに頼っておりました。
ご紹介されたものも拝見して、検討してみます

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マッチしたい文字列の一部が変化する際は、正規表現を使う方法があります。

正規表現の例: `<a href="/[0-9]{4}/company/r[0-9]{9}/">(?<compName>.*?)</a>`

使用例:

```js
const html = `
<p>
  <a href="/2024/company/not-this">not this</a>
  <a href="/2024/company/r308300069/">Foo社</a>
  <a href="/2024/company/r505050505/">Bar社</a> <a href="/2024/company/r505050505/">Baz社</a>
</p>
`

const reg = new RegExp(`<a href="/[0-9]{4}/company/r[0-9]{9}/">(?<compName>.*?)</a>`, "g")

for (const m of html.matchAll(reg)) {
  console.log(m.groups.compName)
}
```

HTMLの構造が単純であればこのような正規表現で十分なこともあります。ただし、扱うHTMLの構造が複雑になると、こういった単純な文字列処理によるアプローチは直ぐに破綻します。これは質問のコードで使用されているParserというライブラリも文字列をHTMLとして解析しているわけでは無いので同じなはずです。

そういった場合は、きちんとHTMLをパースする下記のようなライブラリを使うしか有りません。

- [XML Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/xml-service?hl=ja) （これはXMLとしてパースするので、HTMLによってはパースに失敗します）
- [Cheerio for Google Apps Script](https://github.com/tani/cheeriogs) （これは、有名なライブラリ[cheerio](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio)のApps Script版です。「cheerio」で検索すれば情報も得られ易いでしょう。）

Comment: ありがとうございます。
おっしゃる通りのアプローチで解決したページと、おっしゃっていた通りの理由で破綻したページがありました。

教えていただいたライブラリの使用を検討してみます